# Bash - Faster way to check for file changes than md5?

Tags: mysql, bash, md5

I've got a MySQL DB set up on my system for local testing, and I'm monitoring the tables to see when a change is made.

*Step 1 - Go to DIR*

`cd /usr/local/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64/data/blog_atom_tables/`

*Step 2 - Run Script*

`watchDB`

Where `watchDB()` is (slightly modified for readability)...

```
function watchDB() {
    declare -A aa    // Associative array of filenames and their md5 hashes
    declare k        // Holder for current md5

    prt="0"

    while true; do    // Run forever

        // Loop through all table files within directory
        for i in *.ibd;
        do
            k=$(sudo md5 -q $i)    // md5 of file (table)

            // If table has not been hashed yet
            if [[ ${aa[$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d '.')]} == "" ]]; then

                aa[$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d '.')]=$k

            // If table has been hashed, and diff md5 (i.e. table changed)
            elif [[ ${aa[$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d '.')]} != $k ]]; then

                echo $i;
                aa[$(echo $i | cut -f 1 -d '.')]=$k

            fi
        done
    done
}
```

***TL;DR*** Loop through all the table files within the directory, save a copy of each `md5`, and continue looping through checking for a change.

I don't need to see what rows/columns have been changed, only that the table itself is different. For the most part, this works exactly as I want, but calculating the `md5` for every table takes a noticeable amount of time. For only 25 tables, it takes between 3 and 5 seconds to execute each loop.

Is there a quicker way to do this, other than `md5`? I'd use something like `cmp`, but I need to save a reference of the current state of the file, so I have something to compare it against.

This is only about 1/6 of the total tables that will eventually be in there, so any improvement on speed is welcome.

Comment: Unless `atime` is disabled when the filesystem is mounted, why not monitor the file access/modification times?

Comment: @Birrel All files have it.

Comment: @Birrel Why not use mysql to query the tables for changes...

Comment: @123 It's clunky and slow. The script that I wrote is automatic and runs on all tables in any DB - just set the directory. I often use MySQL Workbench later on to snoop through some of the data, but otherwise I'd prefer a hands-free, automated setup.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer your suggested worked well. Got rid of the md5 and replaced it with `k=$(sudo stat -f "%m" $i)`. If you want to make it an answer, I'll give you the gold.

Comment: @Birrel No it isn't, no way a query on mysql is slower than your solution.

Comment: @123 I'm not talking about the actual function running time. I'm talking about the setup, the amount of code, where it's run, the ease of use, and so on. I'm sure that you have something else in mind than me, but the way I'm imagining it is a lot more cumbersome than I'm interested in. If MySQL Workbench had a "watch tables for changes" feature, that automatically spit-out when changes occurred, then that'd be my go-to. Maybe I'll put something together in the future, but for now this is good enough.

Comment: Don't know why you keep mentioning workbench since you are using the shell?  All you need is `mysql -u user -p pass -e 'query' db` . Can guarantee the query will be shorter than your code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not really checking the content of the file, you could use file system attributes as a simple way to monitor for changes.  Unless the filesystem is mounted with the timestamps disabled, you can monitor the access time and modification time timestamps:

```
stat -f "%m" <filename>
```

The filesystem driver knows when reads and writes occur and subsequently updates the timestamps.